# how to change the background image of a form using open file dialog on another form

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I have a query that. I have a splash form that is my first form of the project and I want to change the background image of that form after that is closed. For example my software starts and after splash form and in setting I have a function to change the background image of the splash form. Can I change the background image when the form is closed? (as my splash form is closed when user enters the setting form).

I have written this code form changing the background image but I don't know how to change the form image when the splash form opens it should open changing the image from the open file dialog.

My code is:

```
var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            FD.Filter = "jpeg files|*.jpg";
            if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileToOpen = FD.FileName;

                System.IO.FileInfo File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FD.FileName);
                BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(FD.FileName); 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try the below

you already set a background image for your splash screen

```
eg : it location was  c:\sam.jpeg
```

Now try the below code on form close event

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Sam.jpeg");
Image.FromFile(FD.FileName).Save(@"C:\Sam.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

now it delete the old file and set the new image on old name...

at the time of reload it shows the new background image...

Comment: sir you have not got my question. read it properly. i said, how to change the image of one form which is closed from the form which is having show dialog option

Comment: sir i dont know how to set the bachground image from the specified location.
how to set the background image from the folder "resoucses as i have all the image in the resources folder?
please if you can help me

Comment: sir the error is coming that this path is not of a legal form
i have written this in the closing event
 Image.FromFile(FD.FileName).Save(@"global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.aquib1", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: You can get the image file from Resource folder like this      string relative = @"Resource\Sam.jpeg";
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath);
string absolute = System.IO.Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, relative);  absolute - have Full path name

Comment: sir i have written this Image.FromFile(FD.FileName).Save("Resources.aquib1.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
but it does not work. no error but the image from the resource is not replacing with the file which i have selected by the open show dialog

Answer (score 1):

You load the splash image from somewhere, so then just replace that image with the one selected by the user with the OpenFileDialog and then the new image will be loaded the next time the splash is shown.

---

EDIT: Further explanation

An example of a solution. Store the image in the same folder as the application (for example: "splash.png") and then you can load that on the Splash Form Load event for example. Now, when the user wants to replace the image from settings with the open file dialog, you simply have to copy the file selected to the application's folder (Application.StartupPath should get you the path to the app folder) and overwrite the old splash.png (maybe you can rename the old one before overwriting or something) and then the next time the application will load, that's the image the Splash form will load.

This is a simple solution that can be improved upon, but as a first attempt it should produce the result you want.

Comment: sir my problem is o am not loading the splash form image from somewhere i have used the background image option to set the image. then how to do?

Comment: Well to obtain this dynamic behavior you have to change that implementation so that it is possible to change it from an outside source. If it is statically specified you will not be able to change it persistently. (i mean, to be changed so that the next time the user starts the splash form will show the new image)

Comment: @shariq_khan i hope i understood you right, you have a splash form that shows only at the start of the application and then closes and from the application settings you can change the image shown in the splash form so that the next times the application will start, it will show another image. If this is correct, then you need to change the way the splash form retrieves the image it uses for background.An example would be from a file in the folder where the application is located for example, so by replacing that you will show another image.

Comment: yes sir you understood righly but then how can i replace the image? and where can i store the images so that it can be replaced? can you explain the answer more deeply as i am a student you can get it by the question itself that i am a newbie to c#. can you please help me if you can

Comment: @shariq_khan i wrote a description of a solution in more detail in my answer

Comment: sir you are telling me to tow store the image in the folder and then to load the splash form image from there but is there any function or method so that i can replace the image from the app folder to the file which i have selected? when i select the file from the users computer then by using file open dialog i have to copy it in the app folder and then replacing it with the same name of splash form image. it can be done by using file open dialog? replacing file name to the origin? can you provide me the code i am totally unknown to this

Comment: @shariq_khan i understand you are new to this but still, stackoverflow is not for this, you should google a bit before. Now, to answer your question, the open file dialog returns the path to the file the user selected, you can do a System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath,destinationPath, shouldOverwrite) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx and that will copy and overwrite. YOu only need to provide the source file path from the openfile dialog and the destionation file path which is tha path of the splash image and send True as the last parameter so that it will overwrite.

Comment: sir i  have wriiten this
System.IO.File.Copy(FD.FileName,"Resources.aquib1.jpg", true);
but it is not replacing with the file. does i have to write code so that it should save the setting to the resources folder which i have maded

Comment: that is because the file path of the splash screen is not Resources.aquib1.jpg :) it's Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "azuib1.jpg". Please, i will stop here, i will not write the code for you, this is not a tutorial site.

Comment: and to top it off, you selected the other answer as being correct even though the code didn't help you...

Comment: no sir that was not my intention. even though i have not reached what i was looking for but i cant mark both of then as answer and as i learnt a lot from both the answer it is not that i have not got anything from both of your answers. i have learnt a lot so i marked.
:)